# Is it possible to let the characters still searchable in an asymptote output?

Tags: asymptote

Consider the following MWE. Sorry, I cannot provide the simpler one.

```
% spiral.tex
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage[inline]{asymptote}

\begin{document}
\begin{asy}    
settings.tex="pdflatex";
settings.prc=false;
settings.render=0;

import graph3;
import math;
size(200);
size3(150,180,100);
defaultpen(fontsize(10pt));

currentprojection=orthographic(camera=(8,6,4),up=Z,target=O,zoom=1);

real x(real t) {return t*cos(2pi*t*3);}
real y(real t) {return t*sin(2pi*t*3);}
real z(real t) {return t;}

real xMax=3, yMax=3, zMax=4;

path3 p=graph(x,y,z,0,2.735,operator ..);
triple P=relpoint(p,0.986);
triple Q=(P.x,P.y,0);

pen spiPen=deepcyan+1.2bp;
draw(p,spiPen,Arrow3(size=3));
dot(P);
label("$P$",P,Z+X);

guide3 h=P--Q;
guide3 rho=O--1.2Q; 

draw(h,  dashed+0.7bp);
draw(rho,dashed+0.7bp);

real arcd=1.5;
guide3 garc=arc(O,arcpoint(O--X,arcd),arcpoint(rho,arcd));
draw(garc,gray,Arrow3(size=3));

label("$z$",h,E);
label("$\rho$",rho,SW);
label("$\phi$",garc,NE);

pen xyzPen=darkblue+1bp;
xaxis3(0,xMax,xyzPen,Arrow3(size=3));
zaxis3("",0,zMax,xyzPen,Arrow3(size=3));

label("$Z$",zMax*Z,SW);
shipout(bbox(Fill(lightyellow)));
\end{asy}
\end{document}
```

Compiling with `Asymptote.bat spiral` produces the following.

[image]

where my batch `Asymptote.bat` is defined as follows.

```
rem Asymptote.bat
echo off

rem %1 TeX input filename without extension

if exist "%~1.pdf" del "%~1.pdf"

if exist "%~1.tex" pdflatex "%~1.tex"

if exist "%~1-*.asy" asy -f pdf %~1-*.asy

if exist "%~1.tex" pdflatex "%~1.tex"

for %%x in (pdf tex asy pre) do (if exist "%~1-*.%%x" del "%~1-*.%%x")

for %%x in (aux log pre) do (if exist "%~1.%%x" del "%~1.%%x")
```

I noticed that the characters in PDF output are not searchable because of conversion. Can we make them still searchable?

### Bonus question:

I **CAN** use `asy -f pdf %~1-*.asy` and why can't I use double quotes in `asy` command, i.e., `asy -f pdf "%~1-*.asy"`?

Comment: Have you tried `asy -f pdf %~n1-*.asy`?

Comment: To get searchable text, `3d`-labels have to be replaced with projected `2d`-labels, like `label("$Z$",project(zMax*Z),SW);` 
instead of `label("$Z$",zMax*Z,SW);`.

Comment: Yes, the "%~n1" means the file name w/o extension. 
You can use `asy` command with double quoted file names as
`asy -f pdf "%~n1-"*.asy`.

Comment: Exactly, while using "%~n1"  
there is no need to to remove extension manually,
it can be invoked as `batch.bat filename.tex`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get searchable text, 3d-labels have to be replaced with projected 2d-labels, like `label("$Z$",project(zMax*Z),SW)` instead of `label("$Z$",zMax*Z,SW)`.

`asy` command with double quoted file names can be used as `asy -f pdf "%~n1-"*.asy`,
here "%~n1" means the file name w/o extension, hence
there is no need to to remove extension manually, it can be used as `batch.bat filename.tex`
or `batch.bat "filename.tex"`.

Comment: But filename with spaces is not possible.

Comment: `batch.bat "file name.tex"`

Comment: I have to invoke `batch.bat "file name"` rather than `batch.bat "file name.tex"` because extension is deliberately not allowed in my batch for the sake of simplicity.